# how to check if https enabled in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url-scheme

I am working on a Spring boot application. I want to print the application details in following format on spring boot startup:

```
- [http|https]://localhost:port/contextPath
```

I am not sure how do I get if https is supported or only http is supported. Can someone please help me.